# How to sort data using Jora in JSON Discovery Report

Tags: json, jora

When creating a JSON Discovery report using jora query language https://github.com/discoveryjs/jora I want to sort data by property value.

Input:

```
[
    {name: 'Elsa'},
    {name: 'Anna'},
    {name: 'Olaf'}
]
```

Output:

```
[
    {name: 'Anna'},
    {name: 'Elsa'},
    {name: 'Olaf'}
]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort data by property value using `sort` method:

```
.sort(<name>)
```

This will sort the items in ascending order, if you want descending order you can use `reverse` method:

```
.sort(<name>).reverse()
```

Output:

```
[
    {name: 'Olaf'},
    {name: 'Elsa'},
    {name: 'Anna'}
]
```